# Sorting Arrays of objects by predefined map of values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, stack

I have the following Arrays:

```
$inputArray = Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 8
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 7
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 5
    )
)

$sortingArray = [5,8,1]
```

I'm looking an efficient way to sort the input array by the id "map of values".. expected output should be $inputArray reordered so that 3rd item would be first, first item would be 2nd etc.

thanks!

Comment: try `usort()`..

Comment: usort as far as i saw is comparing 2 values in array and not against an external map of values...or at least i couldn't find one

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: so far, i have iterated the array of objects and comparing each one to the list.
if found i insert to a new array and unset the value from the $inputArray, but i believe this is sub-optimal, has to be a better way..

Comment: @mickmackusa it is indeed....but the answer here tops the answers there :)

Comment: May I ask the source of this data?  Is this coming from a file? a database?

Comment: the source is partly DB and partly calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a few things here, the main thing is that I use the sorting array as a target for an `array_replace()` and I use `array_column()` to index the objects by (this needs PHP 7.0+ to work with objects)...

```
$input = array_column($inputArray, null, "id");   
$sort = array_fill_keys($sortingArray, null);
$output = array_filter(array_replace($sort, $input));
```

The `array_filter()` will remove any elements which aren't in the input array but in the sorting array.  The `array_fill_keys()` is used instead of `array_flip()` so that I can set a null value, which allows the filter to work.

Comment: i think this is a more elegant approach. works like a charm! 
*the reason that i believe its a preferred method is that it filters duplicates in the original input array and can't fail if key doesnt exist

Comment: I don't expect that `0` will be a valid value for an `id`, but if someone in the future uses this approach, `array_filter()` will destroy them with the `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_flip` to make a temporary array. This will flip the array means the values will be the key.

Use `usort` to sort the array.

```
$tempArr = array_flip( $sortingArray  );
usort($inputArray, function($a, $b) use ( $tempArr ) {
    $tempA = isset( $tempArr[ $a->id ] ) ? $tempArr[ $a->id ] : 999999; //If id does not exist on $sortingArray. Use 999999 as an index
    $tempB = isset( $tempArr[ $b->id ] ) ? $tempArr[ $b->id ] : 999999;
    return $tempA - $tempB;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $inputArray );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if your input array is the result set of a MySQL query, you should be sorting the data via an ORDER BY clause.  `FIELD()` is an excellent tool for the job, with slight weirdness that you need to reverse your sorting logic and write `DESC` after the function.

Resource: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/ (scroll down to "gotcha")

SQL Fiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b996f/1

---

Beyond that, I'll offer two refined versions of Nigel's and Eddie's solutions leveraging some php7+ goodness.  Which one you choose to implement will have to do with:

1. Whether you want to allow elements with duplicate `id` values to "survive" the process
2. Which one performs more efficiently for your *actual* project data (the size of your input array and your custom order array)
3. Personal preference (both snippets can be sensibly written in 3 to 5 lines, so brevity isn't much of a criteria)

### Solution #1: [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [null coalescing operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary)

[PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/LsI37)

```
$array = [
    (object)['id' => 8],
    (object)['id' => 7],
    (object)['id' => 5]
];

$order = [5, 8, 1];  // custom sort order

$order = array_flip($order);  // restructure for easy lookup with isset()
$order[''] = max(array_column($array, 'id')) + 1;  // append value higher than max for outlying ids

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return ($order[$a->id] ?? $order['']) <=> ($order[$b->id] ?? $order['']);
});
var_export($array);
```

*note that I could have passed `$outlier` into the custom function scope as a second `use` argument and replaced all of the `$order['']` variables with `$outlier`, but I opted to append the outlier data into the lookup array.

*I used parentheses in my custom function not only to improve readability, but to guarantee that the evaluation is performed as intended -- I didn't actually bother to check if the evaluation is the same without the parenthetical grouping.

### Solution #2: [array_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) a flipped & filtered sort array with a keyed array

([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/bHZE6))

```
$array = [
    (object)['id' => 8],
    (object)['id' => 7],
    (object)['id' => 5]
];

$order = [5, 8, 1];

$order = array_flip($order);                            // flip for future key comparisons
$keyed = array_column($array, null, 'id');              // declare id values as new keys
$filtered_order = array_intersect_key($order, $keyed);  // remove unwanted order keys
$replaced = array_replace($filtered_order, $keyed);     // apply objects to output array
var_export(array_values($replaced));                    // re-index the output (if desired)
```

*note this won't generate an oversized array of `null` values and it will not remove values that are "falsey".

*I will again state that the use of `array_column()` will damage the data if there are duplicate `id` values in the input array.

Comment: thanks, regarding the SQL it isnt unfortunately...regarding the refactored version of array_search the first response was shorter and more efficient....no?

Comment: The efficiency is very dependent on the size of the arrays involved.  If you mean the `usort()` - `array_search()` answers on the duplicate page, I didn't test against them however, `array_search()` works harder than `isset()`.  The cost to using `isset()` is a single call of `array_flip()` to set it up.  `array_search()` actually traverses the array and `break`s when it finds a match.  `isset()` doesn't do this -- this is the magic of how php processes a hash map.  I am under-qualified to explain this in detail.